# How can I compare argv with an array of elements?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to see if my array of keys created contains the command line argument from `argv`, but I keep getting the error:

```
"incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'const char *';"
```

How is it that I can compare these two arguments found in the code with each other?

```
char *scale_array[] = {"A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"};

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(char)); i += 1) {
        if (strcmp(argv, scale_array[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Found it!");
        }
        else {

        }
```

Comment: Side Note: `sizeof(char)` is invariant (always 1)

Comment: And i think you mean sizeof(char *) not sizeof(char)

Comment: A common idiom is `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` so you don't have to hard-code the type, and then there's no opportunity to get the type wrong.

Comment: so many notes missing! `A♭`? `E#`?

Comment: @RyanHaining `A♭` is the same as `G#`. There is no `E#`.

Comment: @RyanHaining its a program constrained only to sharps.

Comment: @Barmar "A♭ is the same as G#" --> [not always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A♭_(musical_note))

Comment: @chux He's clearly just using the diatonic scale, so they're the same note.

Comment: @Barmar there is an `E#` in the keys of `F#` and `C#`. I think you mean "chromatic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `argv` properly to access the command line input string.
Also the `size of array` has to be determined like this (in your case)

```
(sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(char*))
```

Here is the modified code with multiple command line input.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *scale_array[] = {"A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"};
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(char*)); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[j], scale_array[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Found it! %s \n", argv[j]);
            j++;    
            i = -1;
        }

        if(j == argc)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same index for `argv` and `scale_array`. That will only test if the user gave the arguments in the exact same order that they're in the array. And `argv[0]` isn't an argument, it's the name of the program.

Comment: You need nested loops, not just one loop.

Comment: @Barmar Why nested loop is required? This loop will do the job.

Comment: I didn't notice the `i = -1`, which effectively restarts the loop every time a match is found.

Comment: @chux I corrected the size calculation as well in updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It seems it was as simple as remembering pointers.

Comment: Curious why the mixed size calculation? size_variable/size_type as with `sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(char*)` instead of type/type `sizeof(char**) / sizeof(char*)` or the [robust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161932/how-can-i-compare-argv-with-an-array-of-elements/36162072?noredirect=1#comment59961424_36161932) variable/variable `sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(*scale_array)`?

Comment: @chux `sizeof(char**)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the whole array.

Comment: @Barmar True oops on my part:  `sizeof(char**)` is not the same as  `sizeof(scale_array)`.  Further evidence to use your idea like [`sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161932/how-can-i-compare-argv-with-an-array-of-elements/36162072?noredirect=1#comment59961424_36161932) - less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *scale_array[] = {"A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"};

for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(scale_array) / sizeof(char)); i += 1) {
    if (strcmp(argv[1], scale_array[i]) == 0) {
        printf("Found it!");
    }
    else {

    }
```

assuming your single command line argument is in `argv[1]`, which is the usual case.

Remember that argv is a vector of pointers to character arrays.